# Where/how is my keyboard configuration really defined?

Tags: debian, x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

### **Short version**

What determines which symbol is printed on `<alt>-<KEY>` on Debian 10 (buster) with openbox (i.e. no KDE, GNOME, etc)?

---

### **Long version**

When I type the sequence

```
<q>
<shift>-<q>
<alt>-<q>
<shift>-<alt>-<q>
```

I get the output (in xterm or gvim - firefox, for example, just gives qQqQ)

```
qQñÑ
```

Now I'm particularly interested in the `ñÑ` output, as I can't find any configuration file or command where this behavior would be defined:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

The `xkb_symbols` line seems to indicate that the symbols files `"pc+us+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"` make up my layout. However, none of these even contains an `ntilde` or `Ntilde`. In fact, none of the symbols files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` contains these characters. And the same goes for most of my keys on the `<alt>-<KEY>` and `<shift>-<alt>-<KEY>` levels.

---

### **Additional info**

Similarly, the output of `xmodmap -pke` is just:

```
[...]
keycode  24 = q Q q Q
keycode  25 = w W w W
keycode  26 = e E e E
[...]
```

and so on. So it is inconsistent with the observation that `<alt>-<q>` and `<shift>-<alt>-<q>` give `ñ` and `Ñ` respectively.

Interestingly, when I edit the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` (after having made a backup) to contain, for example:

```
key <AD01> { [ q, 1, 2, 3]};
```

and then reloading this config by `setxkbmap us`, I get from the sequence

```
<q>
<shift>-<q>
<alt>-<q>
<shift>-<alt>-<q>
```

the output

```
q1ñ±
```

i.e. the `<shift>-<KEY>` level is respected and the `<shift>-<alt>-<q>` prints the same as `<alt>-<1>`, while `<alt>-<q>` is unaffected.

---

### What I've tried

```
# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration locales
```

I've been through the manpages of xkbcomp, setxkbmap and many related ones as well as the following resources on the web (amongst others):

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration
2. https://web.archive.org/web/20170825051821/http://madduck.net:80/docs/extending-xkb/
3. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/what-is-the-difference-between-mode_switch-and-iso_level3_switch-4175465999/
4. https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xmodmap.html

I've experimented with many combinations of xkbcomp and co. (as partly outlined in my [question in a different forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=144409)) bringing me to the hypothesis that some program outside xkb seems to be overwriting the keyboard configurations on the shift and alt-shift levels. But I can't figure out what it could be and am completely stuck and would highly appreciate any help on this matter.

---

### Why do I care?

The reason I stumbled onto this, is that I would like to customize my keyboard layout to have it as `us` but with easy access to the German Umlaute (äöü). Previously on openSuSE I was able to achieve this by simply editing the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file.

Comment: Vim treats the `<ALT>` key as _“invert the 8-th bit“_, while `<CTRL>` as _“invert the 7-th bit“_. Therefore if you add `q`, which in Unicode is `U+0071` and `<ALT>`, you get  `U+00F1` or `ñ`. I don't remember if it is configurable.

Comment: Thank you @PiotrP.Karwasz, this resolves the confusion. Indeed, working with right-alt instead my keyboard configurations behave as expected. Would you like to put your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: It is not much of an answer, it is more like a hint. If your **xterm** and **gvim** also had this behaviour, I can't explain why.

Comment: Maybe (just maybe) this page of mine can be helpful: https://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/ (or not. It's quite a mess)

Comment: Thanks @Rmano for sharing your page, I find it very informative for the matter at hand!